# Ayuda,programa deja de funcionar cada que se hace nueva BD con exactamente la misma estructura y relaciones

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, api

Les cuento se esta desarrollando un sistema de inventario, ya se estaba trabajando el los reportes, tal vez un 85% del proyecto, y hace 2 días, lo único que se hizo fue crear una nueva base de datos con la misma estructura e inserts que se generaron directamente desde `phpMyAdmin` para que exactamente no hubiera ningún error,todo con el fin de dejar la base de datos en blanco ya que contenía información de prueba, después de que se hizo esto partes del código `JS` ya no realizaba su respectiva función, es decir en este momento ya no insertaba y no actualizaba, recibe los valores pero no dice ningún error, tengan en cuenta que es lo mismo que de programo desde un inicio y funcionaba perfectamente, hace poco tal vez unas 2 horas se repararon esos errores, realmente se movieron cosas terminando igual que como estaba pero ya funcionaba, se hizo de nuevo la acción de crear otra base de datos y solo cambiamos el nombre en la conexión y de nuevo no inserta y no actualiza, ademas al reparar algo otra cosas mas deja de funcionar, algo que había estado igual desde hace tiempo y hacia perfectamente su función

Alguien me puede decir porque esta pasando esto, que lo causa?

Comment: "hace poco tal vez unas 2 horas se repararon esos errores, realmente se movieron cosas terminando igual que como estaba pero ya funcionaba" busca por ahí

Comment: Es que al final quedo exactamente igual que desde un principio, no se que mover si todo lo que esta es correcto, y es que ya van 3 veces que esta sucediendo esto, estoy segura que si se repara, y hacemos otra base de datos con la misma estructura y demas sucederá los mismo, ademas si volvemos abrir la conexion anterior donde ya estaba funcionando , todo eso se perdio porque ya no lo hace otra vez.

Comment: no podria decirte que hacer ya que nos das puras opiniones para trabajar ni un solo pedaso de codigo imagenes de la conexion a la base de datos ni una consulta desde un script basico asi que te recomiendo corrijas la pregunta incluyas ayuda visual o un codigo simple si no sera reportada!

Comment: Puede ser cualquier cosa el problema.. como esta la pregunta es incontestable... :(

Comment: Es que no tendria caso poner codigo, como lo dije antes, toda la estructura realizada funcionaba perfectamente hasta que se realizo esa accion, y sigue pasando, no es conocienmiento en codigo si no en saber si alguien sabe que podria esta causando eso, no se si me explico :( igual gracias

Comment: @gbianchi Alguien ya ha respondido mi pregunta y parece muy completa, es lo que buscaba que alguien me diera posibles errores y manera de saber, el usuario no ocupo codigo, y se que en el sitio es indispensable y que pueden aplicar comoel "reportar pregunta" o cosas similares, solo dense cuenta que que es un sitio de ayuda.

Comment: @Bryro Se que tampoco es su responsabilidad encontrar la solucion, pero vieron lo facil que fue darme unas opciones para empezar a buscar?   que algunos son moderadores y se toman muy en serio su papel que hasta una pregunta sencilla como por ejemplo " que es una variable" pueden reportarla por que lo he visto y aveces son muy injustos en ayudar algun principiante, que le cuesta poner alguna deficion para ayudar.  Es mi opinion.

Comment: El problema que tiene la pregunta, y por lo cual fue reportada, que la respuesta que diste como aceptada no asegura que siquiera ese sea el problema. La idea del sitio tambien es poder ayudar a otros usuarios a encontrar soluciones a sus problemas. Todos moderamos el sitio, juntos, y la idea es que la pregunta no solo te ayude a vos, si no a todos lo que usamos el mismo.

Comment: Hola, recuerda que es importante realizar las preguntas en base a [ask].

Comment: La di por aceptada ya que fue el unico que su intencion fue ayudarme, lo hubiera hecho con cualquier otro.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Problema: aplicación deja de funcionar cuando se vuelve a la situación inicial de la BD.**

Si indicas que la BD funcionaba inicialmente, y tiene exactamente la misma estructura, ¿y registros? Pero la aplicación ya no funciona cuando se vuelve al punto de partida, se reparan errores, ¿donde? vuelve a funcionar y al volver a "resetear" la BD deja nuevamente de funcionar...

#### Posibles problemas

1. La BD de datos no se encuentra exactamente en el mismo estado en que se encontraba al principio. Suponiendo que la estructura es la misma en cuanto a relaciones y definición de datos, pueden faltar datos necesarios al inicio. Por ejemplo, en un sistema que sitúa eventos en países y ciudades, la situación de partida de la BD tendría registrados una serie de países y sus ciudades.
2. La aplicación actual no es compatible con la BD en su estado inicial. El código ha evolucionado, o se han cambiado configuraciones, de forma que la aplicación requiere datos diferentes o incluso cambios en la propia BD con respecto al inicio.

#### ¿Qué hacer?

1. Descartar que se están persistiendo datos adicionalmente a la BD, por ejemplo en ficheros o hardcodeados.
2. Comprobar cambios en el código. Comprobar que no existan configuraciones de la aplicación que interfieran o cambios en la lógica.
3. Cuando la aplicación está fallando comprobar posibles errores. En PHP [activar todos los errores](http://php.net/manual/es/errorfunc.configuration.php) y ver los logs de errores del servidor. [Comprobar errores de JavaScript en la consola del navegador](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/?hl=es) y hacer [debug de código JS](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/?hl=es).
4. Reducir el set de datos necesarios para el correcto funcionamiento, estableciendo un orden de borrado de datos que se van generando en el día a día para determinar en qué punto el sistema deja de funcionar.

En este punto cabe destacar que si no encuentras lo que está fallando habría que emplear [técnicas de analisis forense de la aplicación](https://www.owasp.org/images/7/7f/ForensicsWebApps.pdf). Se puede profundizar mucho.

De menos a más, podemos usar [Git](https://git-scm.com/) o una herramienta similar para tomar instantáneas de la aplicación en varios estados, por ejemplo haciendo volcados completos de la base de datos y haciendo diff, en el estado inicial (que parece estar fallando) y en el momento en que funciona (¿cuando hemos arreglado cosas?). Lo mismo para el código.

Crear *diagramas de flujo del código* para analizar cómo interactúan las diferentes partes de la aplicación entre sí y con los datos.

***Diagramas de flujo del código.***

Se pueden crear esquemas de llamadas de unas funciones, clases, métodos... a otros, desde el punto de inicio de la aplicación, así como de las consultas a la BD, manipulación de datos en el código, etc.

Comment: Gracias por contestar y darme esos posibles errores, checare lo que me has dicho.